# Looping thru Append Queries using a generic SQL template

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have generated an append query to open a table called 1 and append its contents to a master table called Master.

Master has the exact same structure as table 1. I generated the SQL code using the query wizard Access 2000. The code looks like the following:

```
 INSERT INTO MASTER ( IDNUM, NAME, [DOC TYPE],[PDF FILE NAME]) SELECT [1].NAME, [1].NAME, [1].[DOC TYPE], [1].[PDF FILE NAME  FROM 1;
```

Now I have say ten tables called 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

I would like to loop through the tables appending each to the master. As a result I have one master listing. I know that I can manually create and execute 10 queries.

In the above query def the 1 should be say K so each query would look the same as above but with 2 substituted for the one etc.

So how do I call the generic code

```
INSERT INTO MASTER ( IDNUM, NAME, [DOC TYPE],[PDF FILE NAME]) SELECT [K].NAME, [K].NAME, [K].[DOC TYPE], [K].[PDF FILE NAME  FROM K;

Where K = 1 thru 10
```

Lastly do I need the `;` after `FROM 1`: or `FROM K;`

I want to create a VBA Procedure with all the `Dim`’s etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a variable for a table name.  The best you could do is generate a SQL string and execute it with VBA.

If I were you I would just bite the bullet for having a horrible table design (nothing personal) and do a big `UNION`:

```
INSERT INTO MASTER 
(IDNUM, NAME, [DOC TYPE],[PDF FILE NAME])
SELECT
[1].IDNUM, [1].NAME, [1].[DOC TYPE], [1].[PDF FILE NAME]
UNION
SELECT
[2].IDNUM, [2].NAME, [2].[DOC TYPE], [2].[PDF FILE NAME]
UNION
SELECT
[3].IDNUM, [3].NAME, [3].[DOC TYPE], [3].[PDF FILE NAME]
...
```